# Is it possible to restrict emotion global styles to selected components?

Tags: css, reactjs, emotion

I am integrating some external components into my React project and those components are styled using emotion global styles. I want to limit those styles to just the components I am importing cause it's currently overriding my own CSS styles. My own project is done with tailwind css.

This is what I have done so far but it's not working

```
    const Layout: FC<Props> = ({
      pageClass,
      staticHeader,
      headerColor,
      children,
    }) => {
      const STRONG_ID = "very-strong-id";
    
      const cache = createCache({
        key: "layout",
        prepend: true,
        stylisPlugins: [createExtraScopePlugin(`#${STRONG_ID}`)],
      });
      const { wpcontent: home } = useHomePageQuery();
    
      return (
        <Wrapper className={pageClass}>
          <SEO title="HealthMarkets" description="Your Insurance Marketplace!" />
          <CacheProvider value={cache}>
            <Global styles={Container} />
            <Header staticHeader={staticHeader} color={headerColor} />
    
            <div id={STRONG_ID}>{children}</div>
    
            <Footer>
              <div
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                  __html: home.pageBy?.disclaimers.disclaimer,
                }}
              />
            </Footer>
          </CacheProvider>
        </Wrapper>
      );
    };
    
    
    export default Layout;
```

I am importing the layout which I am using to wrap around my own children but the global styles override everything.

How can I restrict the global styles to just selected imported components?

Comment: What external components in particular?

Comment: @AKX  The layout component itself. Children in this case refer to my own components. I am importing this as a Gatsby theme from one repo to another.

Comment: Well... they're not called global styles for nothing. You could add a prop that entirely disables them, and use that in your other repo.

Comment: @AKX that wont also work because the header and footer styles are controlled by the global styles.

Comment: Then refactor the header and footer styles not to rely on global styles..?