# Limit emotion global styles to a narrower selector

Tags: css, reactjs, emotion

Is there a way to limit the styles that [emotion](https://emotion.sh/) injects into the global scope to a narrower scope?

I've seen [this method](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-morning-8rfur?file=/src/App.js) of using a stylis plugin to add more narrowly-scoped styles, but that only *adds* scoped styles. What I'd like to do is limit *all* styles added by emotion to a particular selector.

The SCSS equivalent of what I'm looking for is something like this, where the styles would only apply to elements where `div#my-styled-div` is an ancestor:

```scss
div#my-styled-div {
  h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    // emotion header styles
  }

  button {
    // emotion button styles
  }
}
```

My use case is a Docusaurus site with a demo page that uses Chakra UI (specifically the [Chakra UI demo page](https://github.com/react-querybuilder/react-querybuilder/blob/migrate-demo-to-website/website/src/pages/react-querybuilder/chakra.tsx) for [`react-querybuilder`](https://react-querybuilder.js.org/)) and I don't want the emotion global styles to affect the Docusaurus theme styles.

([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73583906/is-it-possible-to-restrict-emotion-global-styles-to-selected-components) is similar, but it was never answered and I don't think it's exactly the same issue anyway.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emotion supports SCSS-like nesting, so you can define styles which only apply inside of a specific element like this:

```
import { css } from "@emotion/react";

const myCss = css`
  h1,
  h2,
  h3,
  h4,
  h5,
  h6 {
    color: red;
  }

  button {
    /* ... */
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Emotion styles don't apply to this h2</h2>
      <div css={myCss}>
        <h2>Emotion styles apply to this h2</h2>
        {/* Put the stuff you want to style with Emotion here */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-bash-robcym)

Comment: Oh wow, that's great! However, now I'm thinking this may be a question about Chakra UI rather than emotion. Do you know how to limit the emotion styles that Chakra UI applies to a specific subtree as you've done above?

Comment: If the class names generated by Chakra UI contain Emotion-generated hashes, i.e. the class names look like `css-abcd123`, then there is virtually no risk of the styles applying more widely than intended (due to a class name collision). Are you seeing styles from Chakra being applied outside of the demo that is actually using Chakra? If so, they may be using Emotion's `<Global />` to insert global styles. (Note: never used Chakra.)

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the problem. Chakra has emotion putting selector-free rules into `<head>`, like this: `<style data-emotion="rqb-chakra-emotion-cache-global" data-s="">pre, code, kbd, samp {font-family:SFMono-Regular,Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,monospace;font-size:1em;}</style>`. I've looked through Chakra's documentation and I can't see any way to use hashed or prefixed classes like you describe. Hmmm. (That `data-emotion="rqb-...` thing is custom.)

Comment: @JakeBoone Seems likely that the demo code is bringing in `@chakra-ui/css-reset`, which contains the exact CSS you listed. [Source code](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/5d583e6636029f7777a9db630799a741ff637edd/packages/components/css-reset/src/css-reset.tsx)

Comment: Gah! Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction. Turns out the context provider `ChakraProvider` has a prop called `resetCSS` that can be set to `false` to avoid loading `CSSReset` from `@chakra-ui/css-reset`. Anyone else looking at this should see https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/issues/2802#issuecomment-1186287297 for more information.

Answer (score -1):

I finally found a solution for this. please refer to this link for solution, you can disable CSSReset and host your own CSSReset:
https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/issues/2802#issuecomment-1186287297

you'll end up with something like this:

```
<ChakraProvider resetCSS={false} disableGlobalStyle={true}>
  <MyCSSReset />
  <ColorModeScript initialColorMode={theme.config.initialColorMode} />
  <App />
</ChakraProvider>
```